# Reactive properties issue with vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have run into a baffling issue with reactive properties in a Vue.js app, which probably results from a misunderstanding on my part and I hope someone can help. In my App.vue, I have `import auth from 'src/auth.js'`, and in my data properties I have this:

```
 data() {
  return {
    authenticated: auth.user.authenticated,
    role: auth.user.role
  }
 },
```

This authenticated property is used to show or hide various menu items, e.g:

```
<li v-if="!authenticated">
  <router-link to="/login">Log In</router-link>
</li>
<li v-if="authenticated"><a href="#" @click.prevent="logout">Log Out</a></li>
```

What I'm finding is that changes to 'auth.user.authenticated' (e.g., switching from false to true after a successful login) are not being reflected in the rendering of the menu items - that is, the authenticated data property is not being updated. To do so, I have to explicitly update it in 'beforeUpdate' and the logout method, with `this.authenticated=auth.user.authenticated`. At first I thought it was simply that this was assigned on first creation and not subsequently updated and that if I used a computed property instead, this would be dynamic, but that doesn't do the job either. Clearly my App component is unaware of changes to the 'auth' data. How can I make things so that updating is automatic? I have it working at present but the use of 'beforeUpdate' feels like a kludge.

Comment: try making `authenticated` a computed property that returns `auth.user.authenticated`

Comment: Is `auth` something that is non-Vue?

Comment: thanksd, I did say above that I'd tried using a computer property. But I must have been doing something else wrong, because I just tried again in response to your comment and now I find it works!

Comment: Spoke too soon, in fact. The computed property approach does not work (I thought it did because npm run dev hadn't compiled the changed component - it sometimes does that - and I was still seeing the old version in effect). Roy J, what do you mean by 'Is auth something that is non-Vue'?

Comment: Is `auth` a Vue component, or some object that is not created or managed by Vue?

Comment: No, `auth` is just a Javascript object, with a handful of functions and the aforementioned user object. No use of Vue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue data items are reactive, but non-Vue data items are not reactive. Your code initializes a reactive data item with the value from a non-reactive one.

There is no way for Vue to watch external (to Vue) variables for changes. You will need to notice when your variable changes and [tell Vue about it](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set), or just use the external variable (instead of an internal copy) when you need it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my thinking on this. What I've now done is to store the credentials in a Vuex store on login and logout, and I access this store from a computed property in App. This feels a lot more Vue-y to me than what I had before.